# Correspondence between prime ideals and irreducible algebraic sets

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Let $k$ be an algebraic closed field. The Nullstellensatz theorem prove that
$$I(V(J))=\sqrt{J}$$
and we have
$$V(J)\text{ irreducible }\iff I(V(J)) \text{ prime }$$
So if $J$ is prime, $I(V(J))=J$ is prime, hence $V(J)$ is irreducible.

> If $V(J)$ is irreducible, do we have that $J$ is prime ?

$V(J)$ is irreducible so $I(V(J))=\sqrt{J}$ is prime, but if I'm not mistaken $\sqrt{J}$ prime does not implies that $J$ is prime as well ($J\subset \sqrt{J}$).

> If it is true, does it holds when $k$ is not algebraic closed ?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right; $V(J)$ can be irreducible even if $J$ is not prime.  For instance, take $J=(x^2)\subset k[x]$.  Then $J$ is not prime, since $x\cdot x\in J$ but $x\not\in J$.  But $\sqrt{J}=(x)$ is prime, so $V(J)$ is irreducible.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I agree. But I'm confused, see for exemple here (Miles Reid pdf): https://homepages.warwick.ac.uk/staff/Miles.Reid/MA4A5/UAG.pdf
page 61 the corollary. He says that there is a bijection between irreducible algebraic sets and prime ideals..

Comment: If $J$ is prime, then $V(J)$ is irreducible, and $I(V(J))=J$.  Similarly, if $A$ is irreducible, then $I(A)$ is prime and $V(I(A))=A$.  This means that $V$ and $I$ give inverse bijections between the prime ideals and the irreducible algebraic sets.  It doesn't matter that there are some non-prime ideals that $V$ sends to irreducible sets, since for the bijection above we're restricting the domain of $V$ to just prime ideals.

Comment: Oh yes I understand now. Thank you very much for your help!